# Enabling html PUT method on IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, web-applications, configuration, iis-7.5

I'm doing a **iCal Service** to allow sync between Calendar instances and runs fantastic on **localhost** (under VS2010 Web Server)

But now That I hosted on a Windows 2008 R2 (IIS 7.5.7600) **I couldn't create not even update an event** :-o

**Thunderbird** always said

[image]

So I rush into **Fiddler** and found out the problem

[image]

a **405** error

[image]

That says PUT is not allowed :(

> **How can I enabled this method?** Application Pool? WebSite definition? IIS Settings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We just need to remove the WebDav Service

> Control Panel > Program and Features > Turn Windows features on or off

[image]

then navigate to `Server Manager` > `Roles` > `Web Server (IIS)` and wait until `Roles Services` come up.

Then `Remove Role Service` and Remove `WebDAV Publishing`

[image]

You need to **restart the Server** to finalize this action.

I hope it helps someone

Comment: Surely there must be a better solution than this!

Comment: if you see the date of this post, it tells you that was in 2010... fell free to find a better solution and put here so we all know that better way...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from configuration file.

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
<remove name="WebDAV" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit"
        path="*."
      verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"
      modules="IsapiModule"
      scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll"
      preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64"
      responseBufferLimit="0" />
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Source: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting-http-405-errors-after-publishing-web-api-applications