# How to get .net c# webAPI PUT and DELETE methods / verbs working

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, http-verbs

-Settings

### IIS 7.5 and Visual Studio 2012 4.5

I have create the first webAPI project on my machine. With the code below I can change the type of verb to POST or GET and the request to the server and the response back to the client work perfectly.

As the code is below I keep getting eaither a 405 error code or a 404 not found error code.

My question is is their some type of setting that I need to add to the .config file or a setting that I need to make on the iis7.5 web server so I can get this working?

I have Google this over and over and cannot find the answer to this question.

In my JavaScript file on the client.

```
  $.ajax(
                     {
                         url: "/api/project",
                         type: "PUT",
                         contentType: "application/json",
                         data:'3',
                         success: function (result) {
                            alert(result);
                         }
                     });
```

In the controller in c# class

```
   public void Put(int intt)
    {
        var obj = intt;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Found the magical , elusive link.

http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2011/05/28/resolve-404-in-iis-express-for-put-and-delete-verbs.aspx

I take that back I am getting another server 500 error.

See error below. This one is driving me loco...

[image: IIS 500 Error]

Comment: This solved my problem. It's so ridicilous that Web API provides default GET, POST, PUT and DELETE methods but IIS restricts it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you might need to disable the WebDAV service.  See here:

[Enabling html PUT method on IIS 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946283/enabling-html-put-method-on-iis-7-5)

Comment: I am working on a windows 7 machine. So the role service is not available.

Answer (score 0):

I had the 500 error too and after reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059304/asp-net-web-api-put-with-catch-all-route), I found that if I altered the Content-Type to "application/json" the 500 error code disappeared.

However, I wanted "text/plain" to work, so I followed the tutorial [here](http://myadventuresincoding.wordpress.com/2012/06/19/c-supporting-textplain-in-an-mvc-4-rc-web-api-application/) and I got it to work successfully.

I hope this helps.